# Homeomorphism of the plane that takes a simple closed curve to a circle and is the identity off of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Schoenflies Theorem gives a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(C)$ is a circle. Suppose that $B$ is a closed ball containing $C$ in its interior. Is there a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(C)$ is a circle and $f$ is the identity off of $B$?

Comment: Are you forbidding $f$ from mapping $C$ to a circle entirely outside $B$?

Comment: Hint: The closed region between $\partial B$ and $C$ is homeomorphic to the annulus.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that the answer is yes, and that we can use the homeomorphism as coordinates to change $f$ between the $C$ and the boundary of $B$.